# Code Does not Loop through All folder and Sub folders

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to Loop through all files and sub folders but my code is just works for single folder.

I want to apply this code on all Folders and subfolder which have workbooks.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
    Sub KeepColor()
    Dim strFolder   As String
    Dim strFile     As String
    Dim wbk         As Workbook
    Dim wsh         As Worksheet
    Dim I           As Long
    Dim xRg         As Range
    With Application.FileDialog(4)
        If .Show Then
            strFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "You        't selected a folder!", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    If Right(strFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
        strFolder = strFolder & "\"
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = FALSE
    strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.xls*")
    Do While strFile <> ""
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(strFolder & strFile)
        For Each wsh In wbk.Worksheets
            For Each xRg In wsh.UsedRange
                If xRg.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone Then
                    xRg.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
                Else
                    xRg.Interior.Color = xRg.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
                End If
            Next xRg
            wsh.UsedRange.FormatConditions.Delete
        Next wsh
        wbk.Close SaveChanges:=True
        strFile = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = TRUE
End Sub
```

Comment: there are lots of existing questions here which cover this: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+subfolders

Comment: Thank you very much for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub KeepColor()
    Dim strFolder  As String, fso As Object, parentFolder As Object, folder As Object
    
    With Application.FileDialog(4)
        If .Show Then
            strFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "You didn't select a folder!", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Set parentFolder = fso.GetFolder(strFolder)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ProcessAllFiles parentFolder, "xls*"
    For Each folder In parentFolder.SubFolders
        ProcessAllFiles folder, "xls*"
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub ProcessAllFiles(strFold As Object, fileExt As String)
 Dim fso As Object, objFile As Object, xRg As Range, wbk As Workbook, wsh As Worksheet
 
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

        For Each objFile In strFold.files
           If fso.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name) Like fileExt Then
                Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(objFile.path)
                For Each wsh In wbk.Worksheets
                    For Each xRg In wsh.UsedRange
                        If xRg.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone Then
                            xRg.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
                        Else
                            xRg.Interior.color = xRg.DisplayFormat.Interior.color
                        End If
                    Next xRg
                    wsh.UsedRange.FormatConditions.Delete
                Next wsh
                wbk.Close SaveChanges:=True
           End If
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @FaneDuru its working but it took almost 20 minutes. Because there are 20 Folders and 300+ files with single sheet. Is there any fastest Way to achieve the output.

Comment: If you want to make it faster then you need to do a little work to find out what is taking the most time.  Opening and saving the files ?  Process the cells on each sheet ?  Once you know that you can start to try to improve things.

Comment: @Rajput The iteration between folders and files is fast enough. The problem comes from different directions: Opening and saving these workbooks takes time (depending of the involved workbooks size) and nothing can be done to solve that. But your way of processing can be improved, I think. Looping between each cell and formatting it takes time, too. Now, if you use `DisplayFormat` I can assume that they are conditional formatted. In order to avoid formatting each cell and make the code faster, a `Union` range keeping all cells to be formatted should be used, and format it at the end.

Comment: @Rajput For the blank ones, this can be done. But, in order to do something similar with the colored ones, you should state **which are the involved colors**. Knowing them, so many `Union` should be created and colored at the end, too. Then, it would be good to preliminary check if not **already** `DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex` is the same with `Interior.ColorIndex`. And place the cell in the `Union` range only if this condition is false...

Comment: @Rajput If not something confidential in your workbook and you share it, I will try optimizing your original code.

Answer (score 3):

`Dir` is much faster than `FileSystemObject` if you have a filename pattern, so here's a function which mixes both:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim col As Collection, t
    t = Timer
    Set col = GetMatches("C:\Tester", "*.xls*")
    Debug.Print Timer - t, col.Count
End Sub


'Return a collection of file objects given a starting folder and a file pattern
'  e.g. "*.txt"
'Pass False for last parameter if don't want to check subfolders
Function GetMatches(startFolder As String, filePattern As String, _
                    Optional subFolders As Boolean = True) As Collection

    Dim fso, fldr, f, subFldr, fpath
    Dim colFiles As New Collection
    Dim colSub As New Collection
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    colSub.Add startFolder
    
    Do While colSub.Count > 0
        
        Set fldr = fso.getfolder(colSub(1))
        colSub.Remove 1
        
        If subFolders Then
            For Each subFldr In fldr.subFolders
                colSub.Add subFldr.Path
            Next subFldr
        End If
        
        'this is faster...
        fpath = fldr.Path
        If Right(fpath, 1) <> "\" Then fpath = fpath & "\"
        f = Dir(fpath & filePattern)
        Do While Len(f) > 0
            colFiles.Add fso.getfile(fpath & f)
            f = Dir()
        Loop
        
        'this is slower...
        'For Each f In fldr.Files
        '    If UCase(f.Name) Like filePattern Then colFiles.Add f
        'Next f
        
    Loop
    Set GetMatches = colFiles
End Function
```

Comment: Yes its faster but it does nothing when i remove the data its not keep the color. Whereas @FaneDuru answer is slow but working fine.

Comment: My post is only addressing how to loop over subfolders.  If you want to speed up your code then collecting the cells to be changed in a range (use `Application.Union`) and applying the change to the range after the `For Each xRg` loop may be faster.

Comment: hmm ... I don't think that files in sub-sub-folders will be found - that's why I am using a recursive sub (see findFilesByExtension https://stackoverflow.com/a/69471559/16578424)

Comment: @Ike -  This is just a different approach but it does search the whole directory tree.  You don't *have* to use recursion for that - it just queues up subfolders for searching instead of calling itself again.

Comment: Brilliant! Voted up...

Answer (score 1):

This is a recursion job.

I am using a generic function, that returns a collection of all files (could be changed to array as well) - either for the folder or for *all* subfolders.

You need to add a reference to "Microsoft Scripting runtime"

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub testFindAllFiles()
Dim strFolder As String: strFolder = "XXXX" 'adjust to your needs

Dim colFiles As Collection
Set colFiles = findAllFilesByExtension(strFolder, "xls*", True)

Dim strFile As Variant

For Each strFile In colFiles
    Debug.Print strFile
    'do what you need with the file
Next

End Sub


Public Function findAllFilesByExtension(ByVal targetFolder As String, ByVal extension As String, _
    Optional fWithSubfolders As Boolean = True) As Collection

Dim fso As FileSystemObject: Set fso = New FileSystemObject

Dim colFiles As Collection: Set colFiles = New Collection

findFilesByExtension targetFolder, colFiles, extension, fso, fWithSubfolders

Set findAllFilesByExtension = colFiles

End Function


Private Sub findFilesByExtension(ByVal targetFolder As String, ByRef colFiles As Collection, _
    extension As String, fso As FileSystemObject, fWithSubfolders As Boolean)
    
Dim objFolder As Folder, objFile As File
Dim subFolders As Folders

Set objFolder = fso.GetFolder(targetFolder)

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    If Not objFile.Name Like "~*" Then
        If objFile.Name Like "*." & extension Then
            colFiles.Add objFile.Path
        End If
    End If
Next

If fWithSubfolders = True Then
    Set subFolders = objFolder.subFolders
    For Each objFolder In subFolders
        findFilesByExtension objFolder.Path, colFiles, extension, fso, fWithSubfolders
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: NO its not working, When i remove the data color also removes from the sheet.

Comment: This test-code itself won't do anything to your sheet - you must add the coloring part in the for-each-loop of colFiles. The generic function can be re-used for other requirements - and it is recursive in a complete way. The testFindAllFiles is just an example of how to use it.